# When user inputs same input twice (expected), how do I combine the input to output?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, input

My test code works for the first record with one day entered but the body of the code does not work.  The code continues to run asking for the day and hours worked. I enter "done" and it doesn't accept that either.

I initially thought creating a list for the days entered but wasn't sure when to access the list to print the footer before going to the next input. There are no errors just won't execute as expected.  This is an assignment and many of the declarations were already populated.

Expected Results with user input:

Day worked: Tuesday
Hours Worked: 3
Day worked: Tuesday
Hours Worked: 4
   Day Total 7

Here's my code.

````
HEAD1 = "WEEKLY HOURS WORKED"
DAY_FOOTER = "Day Total "
SENTINEL = "done"   # Named constant for sentinel value
hoursWorked = 0     # Current record hours
hoursTotal = 0      # Hours total for a day
prevDay = ""        # Previous day of week
notDone = True      # loop control
days=[]



# Print two blank lines.
print("\n\n")
# Print heading.
print("\t" + HEAD1)
# Print two blank lines.
print("\n\n")

# Read first record 
dayOfWeek = input("Enter day of week or done to quit: ")
if dayOfWeek  == SENTINEL:
    notDone = False

else:
    hoursWorked =int(input("Enter hours worked: "))
    prevDay = dayOfWeek
    hoursTotal = hoursWorked
    days.append(dayOfWeek)
    print("\t" + DAY_FOOTER + str(hoursTotal))
    print(days)

while notDone == True:
    dayOfWeek = input("Enter day of week or done to quit: ")
    prevDay = dayOfWeek
    hoursWorked =int(input("Enter hours worked: "))
    hoursTotal = 0
    hoursTotal = hoursTotal + hoursWorked
    days.append(dayOfWeek)
    print(days)

    def dayChange(DAY_FOOTER,hoursWorked):
        if dayOfWeek == dayOfWeek:
            DAY_FOOTER = dayOfWeek
            hoursTotal = (hoursWorked + hoursWorked)
            print("\t" + DAY_FOOTER + str(hoursTotal))
            days.append(dayOfWeek)


        else:
            print("\t" + DAY_FOOTER + str(hoursTotal))

def endOfProgram(done):
    if dayOfWeek == "done":
        notDone == False
        return```
````

Comment: In you loop that begins `while notDone == True:`, you are never setting variable `notDone` to `False` based on the input, so you will loop indefinitely. You have defined functions `endOfProgram` and `dayChange` but they are not being called.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code:

First of all, you are not really sensitive to the "done" command within the while loop. You do test the `notDone` variable, but you never write to this variable while inside the loop. The test should be embedded in the loop itself, and is superfluous outside it. Second of all, with each iteration of the while loop you initialize the `hoursTotal` variable to 0, so that you do not memorize the values from the previous days. Perhaps you should use an additional list for keeping track of hours, or use a day_of_the_week:hours dictionary.

Comment: She does test for "done" in every iteration of the loop at the top: `while notDone == True:`. *That* is *not* the problem why the loop does not terminate.

Comment: Sure, I mispoke. What I meant is that notDone is not modified within the loop, and so the condition is insensitive to inputting "done".

Comment: Then maybe you should edit your answer. Just a suggestion.